# Does watermarking images on the fly affect website performance?

Tags: php, performance, .htaccess, gd, watermark

I was considering using GD, PHP, and `.htaccess` to watermark all image files on the fly. How would this affect my site's performance?

Comment: Are you asking a question here, or making a statement?

Comment: @JamWaffles I just check the performance , and i'm really in stress with my wensite performace

Comment: Any request/process that goes through the php cgi will affect performance, tho on the other hand storing/caching watermarked images will require twice as much disk space.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Are you asking _if_ watermarking using GD makes sites slower, or do you want to stress test your server against a lot of requests for watermarked images?

Comment: exactly `a lot of requests for watermarked images` and `On the Fly Watermarking`

Comment: @bizzare this is why we have load balancers...

Comment: @LawrenceCherone OK so is this process recomanded for image protection and copyright enabled web sites ?

Answer (score 1):

Every single hit, adding a watermark, and/or forwarding whats supposed to be a static request a dynamic request is insane. Very good way to promote DOS attacks to your site.

You should add a watermark once, when the image is uploaded, you can have a script to do that, or a cron job to schedule to images that are not on a index to be marked.

Answer (score 1):

You could just cache the watermarked file. Just write it to `filename-watermark.jpg` and use something like the following htaccess to detect if a cached file exist and if so, serve this one instead of redirecting to the php.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/$1-watermark.$2 -f
RewriteRule ^images/([^.]+).([^.]+) images/$1-watermark.$2

RewriteCond $1 !watermark$
RewriteRule ^images/([^.]+).([^.]+) water.php?image=$1.$2
```